# How to remove a certain character from a column in a table

Tags: mysql

I have the following records in my table

```
insert into table foo values (1, '200{');
insert into table foo values (2, '20090{');
insert into table foo values (3, '220{');
insert into table foo values (4, '2000{');
insert into table foo values (5, '5000');
```

I want to replace all rows and remove the "{" character, there are more than 10K records in my table with such a violation. Note: id=5 doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update foo
set column_2 = replace(column_2, '{', '')
where locate(column_2, '{') > 0
```